# Display Mode without Math Mode

Tags: equations, environments

First I want to apologize if the answer to this question is well known. But after some searching, I couldn't uncover any similar questions.

In my document, I would like to feature a regular sentence (with very little math included) using `display mode`. For example, I want the following sentence displayed:

```
\begin{equation}
\textrm{All }x\textrm{ are }y;\textrm{ all }y\textrm{ are }z;\textrm{ therefore, all }x\textrm{ are }z.
\end{equation}
```

I produced that by using the `\begin{equation}` command. However, note that using this command, math mode is automatically included so my sentence becomes italicized unless I wrap everything except my variables in `\textrm{...}`. In this case, I think it would be better if I could do the opposite: "turn off" math mode (so I don't need the `\textrm{...}`), and wrap only my variables with `$$`.

Does anybody know of an alternative to `\begin{equation}` and `\begin{align}` environments without math mode automatically enabled?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What you want is the `center` environment. Using `\begin{center}
content...
\end{center}` you can insert text inside it and use `$...$` for math contents.

Comment: Ah! That's simple! Sorry for not realizing. And is there some way to put an equation label beside it in parentheses, like what happens when using `\begin{equation}` or `\begin{align}`? Thank you!

Comment: @Mathemanic You should (actually) most to check the `amsmath` package [documentation](), there you can find very nice tools for achieve what you asked. First, you can load that package and easily insert text with `\text{}`. You can also use `\tag{}` for customize the numbers and `\eqref{}` for cross reference easily with parentheses.

Comment: As an extension, do you know if it is possible in the `text` mode to have multiple lines of text, aligned at some character? I tried using "&" and "\\" (from the `align` environment), however they did not work out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use `\text` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \text{All $x$ are $y$; all $y$ are $z$; therefore, all $x$ are $z$.}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Alex, is it possible to have multiple lines aligned in `text` mode? I tried using "&" and "\\" (from the `align` environment), however they did not work out. If possible, maybe you could add it to your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Mathemanic Well, then you need to interrupt `\text` and place the `&` signs like `...}&\text{...`.